# Alternative to COUNTIF or AVERAGEIF

Tags: excel, countif

I'm trying to work out a problem where I am constrained from using COUNTIF or AVERAGEIF. The question is as follows:

How would you aggregate data and plot a graph about word count vs reply rate without using COUNTIF or AVERAGE IF?

Comment: And why are you constrained?

Comment: Pivot chart? Could you give an example of your issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a *word count* then you might consider that words are separated from each other by spaces. The length of the phrase/sentence minus the length of the same phrase/sentence with spaces removed will be one less than the number of words.

```
=len(A1)-len(substitute(A1, " ", ""))+1
```

That sounds like it should cover the first scope of your assignment. You will have to provide some additional explanation of what a *reply rate* is.